# How to make instance of one class to be instance of another class in Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl

I'm making an automatic instanctiation of an ontology. let says `Person` with his subclass `FEMALE` and `MALE`.

[image]

During the instanciation, I can create instances of the class `FEMALE` and `MALE`.

for example

```
OntModel model = // Jena model
String   NS    = // the name space

person0 = model.createIndividual(NS + "Allison", "FEMALE");
```

How could I add the fact that `Allisson` in `person0` is also an individual of the class `PERSON`.

I know that a reasoner (Pellet for example) could help here but. But in my case there is a huge number of individuals to instanciate, so the reasoning step become too long for me (about more than 10 hours)

thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
OntClass person = model.createClass( NS + "Person" );
person0.addRDFType( person );
```